# static_assert in a macro but also expand to something that can be used as a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, static-assert

For instance. I have the macro `CHARCOUNT(x)` that expands to `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])`. I would like to use `static_assert` to ensure each macro expansion does a check to see if the result is greater than 2 to avoid someone passing in a pointer to a string and not pointer to an array of characters.

I would like something like this static assert:

```
static_assert(x) > 2
```

This macro would be used to ensure that string copies don't exceed the buffer size such as:

```
TCHAR szMyStr[10];
_tcscpy_s(szMyStr, CHARCOUNT(szMyStr), L"My result");
```

If someone accidentally passes in a pointer where CHARCOUNT would result in the length of the pointer to the string instead of the number of bytes I would like an assert at compile time.

```
const TCHAR* myChars = L"My result";
auto len = CHARCOUNT(myChars);
```

The `CHARCOUNT` above should result in a compile time assert.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Did you mean `static_assert(x > 2)`?

Comment: Avoid macros. Prefer proper (possibly `constexpr`) functions. You ought to throw away that `CHARCOUNT` macro and use [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the code I didn't copy it from my attempts I just typed it. I'm all for doing it the right way over a hack so thank you for suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) instead of that macro, which gives you 0 for unsupported types (e.g. arrays without bounds, non-array types).

For your use case a constexpr function that gives you the size for an array variable would be better suited, like so:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arrsize(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Then you don't need to assert on the size since you can only use the function with actual arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sadly due to requirements to support older Windows versions that also restricted which versions of compilers I have been able to use has stunted my c++11/14 foo. This helps and I can build on knowing about this.